# set::find() doesn't find

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this code (cubeBoxData is a set of cubeBox):

```
cubeBox temp(bx,by,bz);
cubeBoxData.insert(temp);
set<cubeBox>::iterator i = cubeBoxData.find(temp);
const_cast<cubeBox&>(*i).addCube(x,y,z);
```

The problem is that cubeBoxData.find(temp); doesn't find temp, then the program fails trying to call addCube(), and I don`t know why, because this code works fine (just change the third line):

```
cubeBox temp(bx,by,bz);
cubeBoxData.insert(temp);
set<cubeBox>::iterator i = find(cubeBoxData.begin(),cubeBoxData.end(),temp);
const_cast<cubeBox&>(*i).addCube(x,y,z);
```

The operator < for cubeBox is:

```
bool operator<(const cubeBox& c) const {
    return x<c.x ? true : y<c.y ? true : z<c.z ? true : false;
}
```

And addCube doesn't change x, y or z.

I think my operator< is wrong and I'm missing something silly, but i can´t figure what is it.

Comment: Think about your comparison operator very carefully Try something in two dimensions first. Make sure you understand the requirements for the comparison operator. Read documentation and manuals until you understand those.

Comment: Whoa! The operator< is abusing the ternary operator. I suggest refactoring it: return x < c.x || y < c.y || z < c.z;

Comment: @lego: That refactoring would be incorrect, as it would not establish a strict weak ordering (it would be possible for there to be an `a` and `b` such that both `a < b` and `b < a`).

Comment: OK, here's a tip: Can you put [0,1,0] and [1,0,0] in order? (And if you can't, how can C++?)

Comment: The `const_cast` is very questionable too. The operations that are performed under it **must not** change the sort order of the element.

Comment: @Mankarse, the refactoring is correct as it calculates the same value as the original code does. If my suggested refactoring changed that it wouldn't be refactoring anymore, it would be a bugfix. And I wasn't proposing a bugfix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator<` that you have defined does not establish a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). For example, according to your comparator, it is both the case that `{1,0,1} < {0,1,0}` and that `{0,1,0} < {1,0,1}`. As a result, all of the operations on the `set` have undefined behaviour.

You should rewrite your comparison operation so that it does establish a strict weak ordering. The easiest(?) way to do this is to use `std::tuple`:

```
bool operator<(const cubeBox& c) const {
    return std::tie(x,y,z) < std::tie(c.x,c.y,c.z);
}
```

Comment: If you can't use [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), remember that [boost::tie](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#tiers) is a valid alternative.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! The problem is that when x>c.x it should return false and stop checking, I think this should be better:

            return x<c.x ? true : x>c.x ? false : y<c.y ? true : y>c.y ? false : z<c.z ? true : false;                   
The const cast is because "cubeBox" contain a vector of "cubes", maybe I should use a map, but I'm not changing the short, i'm just filling that vector.

Comment: @JotaGe: To be correct, a manual version would have to work as follows: `return x == c.x ? (y == c.y ? (z < c.z) : (y < c.y)) : (x < c.x)`.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate the previous answer:

Elements of a set are const for a reason, you can't just const_cast and modify, because doing so you are not telling the set that it should reorder your element. Since your `addCube` function is probably going to change the sort order of the elements, the correct way to do it is:

```
cubeBox cpy = *i;
cubeBoxData.erase(i);
cpy.addCube(x,y,z);
cubeBoxData.insert(cpy);
```

Comment: As I've wrote, I'm not changing the order, x, y and z still unchanged. The problem was my `operator<`.

Comment: @JotaGe sorry for that so, missed that line